# Facebook api throws an error

Tags: facebook, api

There's a problem with a project I'm working on. The project uses some kind of facebook API with@author Naitik Shah  and version 2.0.4. Yesterday everything was working fine, but today when I try to login I get the following message:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: 200: Requires extended permission: read_stream thrown in /home/vhosts/library/facebook/facebook.php on line 425
```

The function that throws the exception is called _restserver and the piece of code, that throws the exception is:

```
if (is_array($result) && isset($result['error_code'])) {
   throw new FacebookApiException($result);
}
```

When I comment the throw part, it appears that $result does not contain the data I need. Any ideas if this is just a bug that will be fixed by facebook, or if they have banned us from calling the API, or something else?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: 1) Upgrade your SDK 2) show us the code that is actually causing the exception 3) grant the `read_stream` permission!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is straight forward: you must ask more permission from user (`read_stream`) to read user news feed.

Please refer [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/).

Comment: Looks like Facebook has changed the required permissions for some of my actions last night. After adding the new permission and asking the user for this permission everything is OK.